# get third level sub-menu to appear in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi Im attempting to build a menu with jquery, when I click on an anchor I want a sub menu to appear, but when I click on a link within this sub-menu I want another sub-menu to appear.

So , Parent -> Child -> Grandchild

The problem is when I click on Child, it closes that menu as oppose to expanding even more.
Im assuming this is because its reading the Child and applying the same Jquery even though I dont want it to.

http://jsfiddle.net/4AT8C/

```
$("#pop-out-left ul li > a").click(function () {
$("#pop-out-left ul li")
    .not($(this).parent())
    .removeClass("active");
$(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
});

$("#pop-out-left ul li ul li a").click(function () {
$("#pop-out-left ul li ul li")
    .not($(this).parent())
    .removeClass("active");
$(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
});
```

The html...

```
<div id="pop-out-left"> 
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>first</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a> second</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>third level</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>first</a>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <a> second</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>third level</li>
                    </ul>                    
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>first</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a> second</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>third level</li>
                    </ul>                       
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS ...

```
#pop-out-left > ul > li > a + ul {
display: none;
}
#pop-out-left > ul > li.active > a + ul {
display: block;
}

#pop-out-left > ul > li > a + ul > li > ul {
display: none;
}

#pop-out-left > ul > li > a + ul > li.active > ul {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selectors are wrong. For the first one, it is just grabbing any ul li combo in the children. You can do this a bunch of ways. You may want to try and give each one a different class... Here is your code but working.

```
$("#pop-out-left > ul > li > a").click(function () {
    $("#pop-out-left > ul > li")
        .not($(this).parent())
        .removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
});

$("#pop-out-left > ul > li > ul > li > a").click(function () {
    $("#pop-out-left ul > li > ul > li")
        .not($(this).parent())
        .removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, so I was not specific enough in what was being targeted,

Answer (score 0):

Umm....May be you want something like this:

#### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4AT8C/2/)

```
 $("#pop-out-left ul li").click(function () {
   $("> ul",this).show();
   $(this).siblings().removeClass('active').find('ul').hide();
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```